# Getting selected values from one dialog list to another

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm having a problem with following thing:

I have 2 dialog lists: "DL1" and "DL2". "DL1" gets the values from a view with DbColumn method and it is set to "Allow multiple values" so is "DL2". What I'm trying to do is that I need to get the selected values in "DL1" to "DL2". How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set option `Refresh fields on keyword change` for DL1.

Set option `Refresh choices on document refresh` for DL2.

Choose option `Use formula for choises` for DL2 and set formula in Choices to

```
DL1
```